# Android: Diferentes estilos a un mismo TextView

Tags: android, textview

Hay alguna forma de establecer diferentes estilos a un text view, por ejemplo quiero pintar cierto código y quisiera que ciertas palabras, cómo por ejemplo etiquetas `<tag></tag>` salgan de color verde, el texto lo obtengo de un call http, entonces puede tener más o menos etiquetas, hay forma de crear estilos y de alguna forma al `setearle` el texto que le aplique los diferentes estilos a cada palabra?

ejemplo, quisiera que en un textview pudiera imprimir código formateado con estos colores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Andress Blend, saludos! Te recomiendo agregar un ejemplo de exactamente que buscas hacer o si tienes algún código que ya empezaste agregarlo a la pregunta (editando esta pregunta) para captar mejor la idea de lo que planeas desarrollar, créame que se agradece mucho para poder contestar y dar una respuesta buena.

Comment: Andres por favor toma en cuenta lo que comenta Gustavo, es importante realices tus preguntas en base a [ask] para que obtengas soluciones a tus preguntas, saludos!.

Comment: Listo!; he actualizado a como me gustaria que se viera en android